# Is there a horizontal scroll bar in outlook 2007?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007

Just upgraded to office 2007 and can't seem to locate the horizontal scroll bar for outlook; my folder structure goes 10 deep in spots and it's a pain w/o the right / left scroll feature.

Answer (score 0):

I've not been able to get this in the `Mail` view, but I switch to the  `Folder List` view as a workaround.